# Dynamically Change the button from Active to Inactive after removing or adding Items from the cart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-native, react-hooks

I have an "Add" button that is getting inactive immediately after pressing Add and changing the button title to  "Added to Cart". Below is the logic (which is working well)

```
const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

<Button onPress={() => (props.addItemToCart(props.id), setDisabled(true))} disabled={disabled} title={!disabled ? "Add" : "Added to Cart"}/>
```

I want the button to be active again whenever the product removed from the cart. I have below which has items that are already in cart.

```
const cartProducts = props.cartSlice;
const itemExistsinCart = cartProducts.map((item, i) => item.product);
```

console.log(itemExistsinCart) output [sample products in the cart]

```
Array [
  "5f15d964e520d44421ed8e9c",
  "5f15d9b3e520d44421ed8e9d",
  "62e5285f92b4fde9dc8a384c",
]
```

What I want is to have the button active again only for the individual products if I remove the said products from the cart. Any ideas and suggestions on how to go about it are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: You should update the `disabled` property against each product object. So that it will update the disabled state individually.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing your entire code, but I suppose your cart and your product list are in different components, right?

So you need to control your application context, there are many ways to do that. I recommend you to take a look in React Context https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-context-for-beginners/

Comment: @Cota yes the cart and product list are different components. I only shared the code sections that are relevant to my question. I'm relatively new and actually using React Context for user management and redux for the cart. Ill go through the tutorial to see if react context can solve the problem am facing.

Comment: you don't need to use both, redux and context, choose one to make you code better readable

Answer (score 0):

If you have unique ids for every item. Use it to cross-check it in the cart. If you view the current item, create a function that checks the cart if the item is existing then the button will be disabled else if it isn't then enabled it.

Comment: Yes the IDs are unique. I thought of that. and i believe it would work. Something to the effect that if props.id that I intend to add to cart is in the  itemExistsinCart array then disable or enable the button. I got stuck at writing the actual implementation code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use the .some() method to check the item present in the cart.

Replace the code with this:

```
<Button onPress={() => (props.addItemToCart(props.id))} disabled={props.cartSlice.some(item => item.product==props.id)} title={!(props.cartSlice.some(item => item.product==props.id)) ? "Add" : "Added to Cart"}/>
```

Comment: that worked. Exactly what I wanted to achieve. Thanks a lot.